# Checking data string fits a 6 digit number format from input file

Tags: java, regex

I got some data.txt file with N-string. Each string consists of 6 digits separating by space. I need to read this but before I need to check data format (I mean that each line must consist only 6 and only digits).

Do I need to use regexp?

Comment: Well, be bold and try it :) Feel free to come back with any problems you encounter when using regex to solve this!

Comment: If the task is so easy and specific, you could use a loop to check all the characters, but why bother?

Comment: Regexp allows you to match simple stateless patterns. In your case, it will fit OK.

Comment: have you tried any code yet?! if yes, please post. So everyone can help you! :)

Comment: No, you do not need a regex here, but you can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with a regex.

One way to do this is to check if for each row you read, you have digits only, and add a constraint for the number of digits. The digits part can be done pretty easily, using a "`/d`" while the number of characters to be used is constrained by "`{desiredNumber}`".

To better understand regex in Java, use this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) :D

If you still cannot solve it, this is the magic line:

```
if (!newLine.matches("\\d{6}")) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: No he doesn't.  There are plenty of other ways in which this can be done.  E.g. convert to int, then check if `100000 ≤ result ≤ 999999`.

Comment: Thanks, a lot!Now it works

Comment: @tarleb he might also have other non-digit characters which would result in an exception being thrown while parsing the alleged numbers;

Comment: @SummerCode Exactly. Catch those exceptions and you are still golden.  However, my suggestion assumes that numbers cannot start with 0, so it's actually wrong (good catch!). The main point still stands though, there *are* different methods.

Comment: Yes, there are many methods indeed, that is definitely correct

Comment: Too bad you denied him the pleasure to get to know regex by himself.